# React Router - Change state of other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

When using React Router, how can I change the state of another component when the page is being routed?

For example, I have an app structured like this:

```
Header
==Link1 Link2==
Footer: "You are now at Home", button1, button2
```

When the user is routed to Link1, I would like to update the state of the footer so that it knows that it is currently on link1. For example, the footer is a toolbar, and some buttons will be disabled on Link1, but all buttons will be available on both Link2 and Home. Like this:

```
==Header==
==Link1 Link2==
==Content of Link1==
Footer: "You are now at Link1", button2
```

The solution I can think of is to wrap both the footer and content of the links into a big, single component, and set up routes to that whole component. But I'm not sure if this is a good practice, since I guess it kind of defeats the purpose of a "footer".

Another thought is that maybe I can change the state of the footer component when routing is in action, so the footer will re-render when it's necessary. The `<Footer />` component thus sits outside of the main contents, on the same level like the `<Header />`. However, I have no idea how to do this.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Here is the code snippet on CodeSandbox, I hope it could illustrate my problem better.

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/r4l74pkx3o)

Comment: Cant we use location.pathname to judge what to render and what not to render in footer. The example sandbox that you mentioned doesnot have any history passed through Browserrouter, hence i tried using location.pathname. Butif you are passing any history along your tree, you can make use of this.props.history

Comment: @stack26 Hi, thanks for the reply but I'm not sure if I follow. Do we have to inspect the current URL or history to do this? Is it possible to let the router fire a simple signal to the `Footer` component and up its state? (not sure if what I want is an anti-pattern with React...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go would be to use the [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC on the `Footer` so that it receives the props when the route is changed.

Changes to code

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

then

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/section1" component={SectionOne} />
    <WrappedFooter />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and then

```
const WrappedFooter = withRouter(Footer);
```

You can now use the `this.props.location.pathname` inside the footer to access the currently matched route from the router. You should use the actual path in your switch
    let text,
        {location} = this.props

```
switch (location.pathname) {
  case '/': {
    text = 'Home'
    break
  }
  case '/section1': {
    text = 'Section One'
    break
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/8y051k9qoj